# Program to print the digits of numbers, in words

Tags: c, codeblocks

I wrote a program the prints the digits of the numbers that I entered in the terminal in words. Ex, 123 would return one two three. When I try to run the program, after I put in my number, it's saying the program has stopped working. I use Codeblocks. Is there anything wrong with the code? It's compiling but it's returning the error -1073741510.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   long long int m = 0, n, digit;

   printf ("Whats your number? \n");
   scanf ("%lli", &n);

   if (n < 0){
      n = -n;
      printf ("negative ");
   }

   if (n = 0)
      printf ("zero ");

   else {
      while (n != 0){                     //this is to reverse the number
         m = m*10 + n%10;
         n = n/10;
      }

      while (m != 0){
         digit = m%10;
         switch (digit){

            case 0:
               printf ("zero ");
               break;
            case 1:
               printf ("one ");
               break;
            case 2:
               printf ("two ");
               break;
            case 3:
               printf ("three ");
               break;
            case 4:
               printf ("four ");
               break;
            case 5:
               printf ("five ");
               break;
            case 6:
               printf ("six ");
               break;
            case 7:
               printf ("seven ");
               break;
            case 8:
               printf ("eight ");
               break;
            case 9:
               printf ("nine ");
               break;
         }
         m = m / 10;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
scanf ("%lli", n);
```

It needs to be:

```
scanf ("%lli", &n);
```

scanf's argument needs to be the address of a variable to put the result into.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
scanf ("%lli", n);
```

needs to be

```
scanf ("%lli", &n);
```

Better still, check the return value of the function to make sure that reading of the input was successful.

```
if ( scanf("%lli", &n) != 1 )
{
   // Error in reading the input.
   // Deal with the error
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand that last part.

Comment: If the user typed in something that is not a number, say `l234` instead `1234`, then you will be able to catch the error and deal with it.

Comment: @RSahu - Just an observation:  the _text_ version of the number in your comment is almost indistinguishable from the numeric version.  Try using double quotes around digits. "1234"

Comment: @ryyker, that was on purpose :) To present an example where it is easy for humans to make such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must switch based on digit and not on m

```
     digit = m%10;
     switch (m){

     case 0:
           printf ("zero ");
           break;
```

must be

```
     digit = m%10;
     switch (digit){

     case 0:
           printf ("zero ");
           break;
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can change this line:

```
scanf ("%lli", n);  //passed variable
```

To this:

```
scanf ("%lli", &n); //  
//      ^       ^   // Always: When you need to change the value of an 
                     // argument, you need to pass the address 
                     // of the value, not the value itself.
```

***Edit*** (to answer question in comments)
You are *changing* the value of ***n*** to 0 before it is able to be evaluated properly. You want to *compare* it.  Once the following edit is made, input seems to be processed correctly...
***Change the line***:

```
if (n = 0) //ASSIGNS value of 0 to value of n
```

to

```
if (n == 0) //COMPARES value of 0 to value of n
```

Comment: is the space really required in this case?

Comment: @NatashaDutta - Not _necessary_, but white space in the format string matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.  In this case, `\n` will precede the input.

Comment: yea, but it's still not working, even after I switched based on digit

Comment: @Rockstar5645 - depending on how you have your environment set, I wonder if " %lld" would work for you?.  What is the error message?

Comment: @ryyker - I fixed the ampersand issue and I changed the expression of the switch statement to digit, but after I type in a number in my terminal, it's just returning the process as 0. There isn't even an error message anymore.

Comment: @ryyker `"%lli"` will consume leading white-space, even without the `"  "`.  The space is _not_needed. "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier." C11 §7.21.6.2 8

Comment: @chux - Yep. You're right.  Had to ***[look it up](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)***, again....  Edited.  And thanks for your reference.

Comment: @NatashaDutta - Sorry for mis-information about leading space in format specifier.  See Chux reference above, and I edited my answer (again) to reflect the correction.  Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the input as characters rather than digits.

You can also use an array for the digit text:

```
const char number_as_text[] = "1234";
const char * digit_names[] = 
{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
  "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

const unsigned int length = strlen(number_as_text);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
  unsigned int digit_value = number_as_text[i] - '0';
  puts(digit_names[i]);
  puts("\n");
}
```

This should also be faster because there is no division operations.  Most processors don't like division and division slows them down.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing will fail for large numbers whose reversed pattern does not fit in a `long long`.  Use recursion instead.

Various improvements commented below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void int_text_helper(long long neg_x) {
  if (neg_x <= -10) {
    int_text_helper(neg_x / 10);
    fputc(' ', stdout);
  }
  int digit = -(neg_x % 10);
  static const char *text[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
      "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
  fputs(text[digit], stdout);
}

int main(void) {
  long long int n; // m = 0, n, digit;
  // printf("Whats your number? \n");  Typo
  printf("What's your number? \n");
  // Note: this will read numbers like 0123 and an octal number.
  scanf("%lli", &n);

  // Let us work with negative numbers instead so code can handle LLONG_MIN.
  if (n < 0) {
    fputs("negative ", stdout);
  } else {
    n = -n;
  }

  // Use do loop (or recursion), so no special case with 0
  // if (n = 0) printf("zero ");

  // Let us use recursion rather than reversing the number.
  // Reverse fails for a number like 9223372036854775799 (Near LLONG_MAX)
  int_text_helper(n);

  return 0;
}

-9223372036854775808
negative nine two two three three seven two zero three six eight five four seven seven five eight zero eight
```